# Can't upload recorded video mediaBlobUrl to server using ReactJs

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I'm creating a web app where user's recorded video will be uploaded to a server. I'm using `react-media-recorder` for recording video. It's giving me a `mediaBlobUrl` of the recorded video. The format of url is like this - `blob:http://localhost:3000/5ef1cbb6-3e97-4c09-a47b-296e822b9839`. I'm trying everything to send this video to a server but unable to do it. How can I do this using react and node js? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

you must put data into formData like this

```
var fd = new FormData();
fd.append('foo', 'bar.mp4');
fd.append('data', soundBlob);
```

Comment: I get a mediaBlobUrl. So should I use a state where I set the value of the state to mediaBlobUrl and then I append the state value in the formData? And what do the third line does?

Comment: in the third line you must put the state
in the second line you must put the name that depend on your back end developer

Comment: Doesn't work. Gives me an empty formData even after appending the state value to the formData.

Comment: can you give some info about what the backend devs said to you?
how must you send data to back?

Answer (score 0):

Check this URL
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-media-recorder

```
import { useReactMediaRecorder } from "react-media-recorder";

const RecordView = () => {
  const { status, startRecording, stopRecording, mediaBlobUrl } =
    useReactMediaRecorder({ video: true });

  return (
    <div>
      <p>{status}</p>
      <button onClick={startRecording}>Start Recording</button>
      <button onClick={stopRecording}>Stop Recording</button>
      <video src={mediaBlobUrl} controls autoPlay loop />
    </div>
  );
};
```

And find out how to communicate with the server.

Just send the URL to the api provided by the server.

Comment: I used this code already. I get a mediaBlobUrl for the recorded video. So should I use a state where I set the value of the state to mediaBlobUrl and then I append the state value in the formData?